# What is the simplest and most efficient way to get the first and last date of the previous month?

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to get the first and last day of the previous month. What I really need is a range for a `BETWEEN` clause, so I need the first second of the first day, and the last second of the last day.

This is the code I've been using:

```
set @startDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate())), 0)
set @endDate = dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()  ), 0))
```

However, for today, this is actually returning 4/1/2011 and 5/1/2011, which is not completely accurate. I want to get the last second of 4/30/2011 for the endDate.

I've been googling and I see many different ways to get the first/last day of a month. Even on SO itself, I see many different variations of this question with many different answers. I'd like to compile a list of all the methods to achieve this, and then determine which is the "best" (based on simplicity and efficiency)

(I should add that I'm using sql server 2000)

**EDIT:**

Re the enddate bug - this code is actually correct, the problem was just that `@endDate` was a smalldatetime. I changed it to a datetime and this is now working correctly

Comment: Re: The Edit.  This is an example of how using `>= AND <` reduces the scope for errors, bugs, complexities, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dates I strongly recommend not using `BETWEEN`.  This is highlighted by your need to remove 3ms from a date to get "the last moment of the previous day".

With continuous values (rather than discrete values), that can have varying degrees of accuracy, it is generally better to use `>= AND <`.  For example...

```
WHERE myDateField >= '2012-04-01' AND myDateField < '2012-05-01'
```

By doing this you never need to even think about the accuracy of the `myDateField` data or data-type.  It just works.  Always.

With that in mind, your code is very close to what I would use...

```
SET @start = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()) - 1, 0)
SET @end   = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate())    , 0)
```

Comment: thanks, I see your point... It's definitely more accurate, though "between" is a cleaner (or just wordier :) ) indication of what I'm trying to do. But I think accuracy trumps that :) If I end up using this code, I'll accept the answer

Comment: @froadie - I agre that `BETWEEN` feels like neater code.  And it's perfect for discrete value (such as `BETWEEN 0 and 9`).  Unfortunately, it simply doesn't work so well with with continuous values; you're forced into making an *approximation* of the end boundary condition.  (Who would do `BETWEEN 0 AND 9.99999` for example?)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as per the explanation from @Dems (please see the comments)

I think now my answer will be same as @Dems to we both are have same answers. :) @Dems Credit goes to you.

try this query it will get you the proper dates as per your need.

```
select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())), 0)
select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()  ), 0)
```

and using this date you can directly use the `>= and <` as per the suggestion by @Dems below.

Comment: Note: This gets the last day of the month, but at `00:00` in the morning. The The OP uses `-3ms` to get the last 'moment' of that day.

Comment: Yes i have done it with purpose, if using `>= AND <=` method to find the data it will be easy to manage, with only dates.

Comment: I don't suggest `>= AND <=`. I suggest `>= AND <`. This avoids the need to subtract 1 day, 3ms, or whatever.

Comment: ok! i got your point! thanks for making me clear the concept.